# SQL Query, remove duplicate entry based on another column highest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I'm working on alerts extraction from SCOM SQL server

I have some issue on alert duplication, as each time an alert status is changed (from new to acknowledge for example), a new entry with same alert_id is created on database.

So i'm trying to deduplicate these alert_id, based on the highest alert status (0 mean new, 100 Acknowledge, 255 mean closed).

Ex:

```
row   alert_id                              alert_timeraised  ResolutionState
1     4B77E4A8-61F9-4696-A4C0-00076EDACCE7  2019-06-24        0
2     4B77E4A8-61F9-4696-A4C0-00076EDACCE7  2019-06-24        100
3     4B77E4A8-61F9-4696-A4C0-00076EDACCE7  2019-06-24        255
4     C6BF2104-767D-43E0-B356-000B30570312  2019-07-07        255
5     C6BF2104-767D-43E0-B356-000B30570312  2019-07-07        0
```

For the row 1 and 2 (Same alert_id), i would like to select only the row with the hight "ResolutionState" Value (255)

What i've tried :

GROUP BY statement (each time i get a different count ...)
SELECT UNIQUE (not working at all)
WHERE with select

Her is the sql query :

```
SELECT

Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid AS 'alert_id',
Alert.vAlertResolutionState.StateSetDateTime AS 'alert_timeraised', 
ResolutionState

FROM

Alert.vAlertDetail WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Alert.vAlert WITH (NOLOCK) ON Alert.vAlertDetail.AlertGuid = Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid 
INNER JOIN Alert.vAlertResolutionState ON Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid = Alert.vAlertResolutionState.AlertGuid

GROUP BY 
Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid,
Alert.vAlertResolutionState.StateSetDateTime,
Alert.vAlertResolutionState.ResolutionState

UNION

SELECT
Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Alert.vAlertResolutionState.StateSetDateTime, 20),
ResolutionState

FROM
Alert.vAlertDetail WITH (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN Alert.vAlert WITH (NOLOCK) ON Alert.vAlertDetail.AlertGuid = Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid
INNER JOIN Alert.vAlertResolutionState ON Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid = Alert.vAlertResolutionState.AlertGuid

GROUP BY
Alert.vAlert.AlertGuid,
Alert.vAlertResolutionState.StateSetDateTime,
Alert.vAlertResolutionState.ResolutionState

ORDER BY alert_id asc
```

Thanks a lot if you have any proposal for this ..

Comment: Please do no just answer "duplicate", i have no solution for the moment.,, I've tried group by, subquery, where ...   I'm not SQL master :(